# Set default shell for existing user with puppet

Tags: linux, puppet

I'd like to set the default shell to zsh in Puppet. Preferably for the current user because I just run my modules as `puppet apply mymodule.pp` since I store my configuration that I use across multiple machines in git.

How can I set the default shell using puppet?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want to set the shell of an existing user, simply do:

```
user { "theuser":
  ensure => present,
  shell  => "/bin/zsh",
}
```

If you want to set the shell of whatever user Puppet is happening to run as, you can make use of the `$id` fact which returns the name of the current user. This feels a little bit magical to me, and may result in undesired outcomes, like if you're running as the `puppet` user with a `puppet agent` run and you end up setting a shell for a user that shouldn't have interactive logins.

That would be done like:

```
user { $id:
  ensure => present,
  shell  => "/bin/zsh",
}
```

Note: the "ensure => present" is optional.

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately setting the shell requires superuser privileges and hence I can't use $id as it points to root. I also added the required quotes around the shell variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify user shell when you realize the user, which should be created as a virtual resource. See or search for puppet best practices to get details.

Comment: What happens if the user already exists?

Comment: is that exacty the same user? if so, puppet should update the default shell from the recipe. if the same uid but different user, then you have a conflict and you need to remove the user with the uid in the system so that puppet will run. however,